# Get all child models from a model without looping?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have 2 models:

```
class Books < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :library_books
  has_many :libraries, through: :library_books
end

class Library < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :library_books
  has_many :books, through: :library_books
end
```

I run a query that is similar to:

```
books = Book.joins(:libraries).where("title LIKE ?", "%somevalue%")
```

This query works and gets all the books of a certain title from all libraries.  However, I'm trying to get all the libraries from the list of books that I have.  I am able to get each library if I do:

```
books.each do |b|
  libraries = b.libraries

  # Do something with the libraries
end
```

However, there has to be an easier way to do this without looping through each book.  How would I get all the libraries without having to loop through each book to get them in a query (and remove any duplicate libraries that might show up)?  Is it possible?

As always, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
libraries = Book.where("title LIKE ?", "%somevalue%").preload(:libraries).flat_map(&:libraries)
```

Or even better:

```
libraries = Library.joins(:books).where("books.title LIKE ?", "%somevalue%").uniq
```

If you need both books and libraries:

```
books = Book.where("title LIKE ?", "%somevalue%").preload(:libraries)
libraries = books.flat_map(:libraries).uniq
```

Comment: Thanks! The first query worked great.  Does this check for uniqueness?  Forgive my ignorance, I'm new to Ruby and Rails.

Comment: @Sean - Hi, the first query might have some duplicates if `libraries` is a many-to-many associations.  Second query is save though, also, it is much cleaner.

Comment: Well, I need data from both the books and libraries.  But I need all books and all libraries (but only unique libraries).  Is there a way to accomplish both using similar queries you have provided?

Comment: Answered my own questions.  Adding "uniq" to end of the libraries did accomplish uniqueness as well.  Thanks again!